# Store values in an array in php

Tags: php

I want to store values like `A1,A8`, `B1,B8`, `C1,C8`.. and till `H1,H8` in an array.

```
$char = 'A';
$window=array();

for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
{
   echo $char."1";
   echo $char++."8";
}
```

This for loop prints the data A1,A8 TO H1,H8.

I want to store these values in array `window`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What does "in array window" mean?

Comment: @lonesomeday in the array called window I imagine.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what output you want, not least of all because your code doesn't do what you say it does.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$array[] = newvalue` syntax:

```
$char   = 'A';
$window = Array();

for ($i=0;$i<8;$i++) {
   $window[] = $char . "1" . $char . "8";
   $char++;
}
```

Comment: I know I'm being massively pedantic but he did say he wants the values separated with a `,` :P

Comment: @martswite: I decided to ignore that, because his existing code does not do that (despite apparent claims to the contrary). I cannot be sure whether he meant the comma to literally be part of the output. So he can figure that out himself.

Comment: @martswite: It's a _huge_ world, but think of all the people you've met on Stack Overflow who aren't from Nottingham, then notice that the expected odds match up completely :P

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$char = 'A';
$window=array();

for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
{
   $window[] = $char."1," . $char++ . "8";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :
array_push

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php